# stop outer div 100% of screen width

Tags: html, css

I am stuck on some css coding for simple divs. I have an outer div with two inner divs. I am floating the 2 inner divs so when the screen width goes below 1200px the 2 inner divs are on top of each other. All this is fine and what I want. The problem I have is that when the screen is below 1200px and the 2 inner divs are on top of each other, the outer div is still at 100% of the screen sidth. I dont want this but want the outer div to shrink to always be the width of the inner divs. I have tried many things but no luck. Thanks - here is my code.

```
<style type="text/css">
   #Panel {
      float: left;
      background: #3CA6F0;
      padding: 10px;
   }
</style>


<div id="Panel">
   <div style="width: 600px; display:inline-block; background-color: #eee;">1</div>
   <div style="width: 600px; display:inline-block; background-color: #eee;">2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you make a codepen or a jsfiddle that represents your problem?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/A43g9/ you can only see my problem when you minimise screen

Answer (score 0):

From so far i understanded your question, i gave the `div`s inside the `#Panel` the css property's of `float: left` and a `width` of `50%`.

```
   #Panel {
       background: #3CA6F0;
   }
   #Panel > div {
       width: 50%;
       background: #ddd;
       float: left;
   }
```

This makes them float next to each other.

[**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/9rUuf/)

---

**EDIT**

With this piece of code under it:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    #Panel > div {
        width: 100%;
}
```

The 2 `div`s will stack up to each other.

[**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/9rUuf/1/)

Comment: Thanks but I wanted to keep my original css for the inner divs as  well

Comment: i want the inner divs to behave as they do now - side by side on larger screens but on top of each other on smaller screens. My problem is the outer div stays at the screen width when the inner 2 are on top of each other on smaller screens and want the outer div to be only the width of the inner div.

Comment: Oo okay, ill do it when i get home :)